# Transfer X% of Eth. sent to smart contract, to contract owner on buy function call

Tags: solidity, contract-development, address.transfer

I use this "buy" function in a smart contract, to receive Eth. for a token. 
I would like to extend the function, so if the Eth amount in a transaction is higher than X Eth. then send Y% to smart contract owner.

I'm not sure about what would be the best way to do this, so I'm looking for any suggestions.

Thanks in advance :-)

```
/**
 @dev Buy tokens with ether. 
 @param minPurchaseReturn The minimum number of tokens you will accept.
 */
function buy(uint minPurchaseReturn) public payable {
    uint amount = formulaContract.calculatePurchaseReturn(
        (tokenContract.totalSupply() - uncirculatedSupplyCount) - tokenContract.balanceOf(this),
        (address(this).balance + virtualReserveBalance) - msg.value,
        weight,
        msg.value);
    amount = (amount - ((amount * fee) / 1000000));

    //Now do the trade if conditions are met
    require (enabled);
    require (amount >= minPurchaseReturn);
    require (tokenContract.balanceOf(this) >= amount);

    //Accounting - so we can pull the fees out without changing the balance
    collectedFees += (msg.value * fee) / 1000000;

    emit Buy(msg.sender, msg.value, amount);
    tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
}
```

Comment: `if the Eth amount in a transaction is higher than X Eth` - there is no `if` in your code, to begin with.

Comment: Also, it looks extremely similar to [Bancor Contracts](https://github.com/bancorprotocol/contracts). Have you tried consulting with them via GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the amount of Eth coming in `msg.value`, so use it in your calculations. Add something like this:

```
uint threshold = 1 ether;
uint percentage = 5;

function buy(uint minPurchaseReturn) public payable {
    ...
    if(msg.value > threshold){
        //the following line introduces no overflow risk
        //since there's not enough Ether to overflow uint256 
        //by multiplying msg.value by 100
        uint myPrecious = msg.value * percentage / 100; 
        _owner.transfer(myPrecious);
    }
    ...
```

You can inherit [Ownable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol) to get `_owner` value.

Comment: `msg.value / 100 * percentage` is a bad idea. You probably want `msg.value * percentage / 100`.

Comment: @goodvibration well, just multiplying by 100 isn't very likely to cause an overflow, but then again - you never know ;) So it may require additional checks. With `/ 100 * percentage` you get less precision, but no overflow risk. Is precision loss the reason why you don't like it?

Comment: The value of `percentage` is at most 100, right? In order for `msg.value * percentage` to overflow, `msg.value` would need to be at least `2 ^ 256 / 100` wei, which means `2 ^ 256 / 10 ^ 16` Ether. That amount of Ether doesn't even exist, so no overflow is ever likely there.

Comment: Thank you all, and that you @utgarda for providing me with an example. I've got my contract working now :-)